# How to extract data from Offchain storage?

Tags: rpc, substrate

I'm trying to access data that I'm storing through the RPC off-chain endpoint.
[image]
I've used OffchainStorage::get() with default config but not getting any data back.

Is there anything do I need to set up explicitly to extract the stored data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the client-side we can get the off-chain storage instance from shared backend instance *(which is of type Arc < FullBanckend >)*.
This instance can be find inside *new_full()*.

After getting the Bankend's shared instance, we can access our off-chain storage like this:

```
// The relevant ocw storage instance.
let ocw_storage = backend.offchain_storage();

// Prefix for accessing values for our application.
let prefix = &sp_offchain::STORAGE_PREFIX;

// Get our value
ocw_storage.get(prefix, key);
```